Android ViewModel MutableStateFlow Type Mismatch
When working with MutableStateFlow in my viewmodel, I got the following compile error:  "Type mismatch. Required: Bar, Found: Unit"
Here is my stripped-down code:
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.update

class Bar(
    val name : String = "",
    val id : Int = 0
)

class TestViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _testState = MutableStateFlow(Bar())

    fun foo() {
        _testState.update {
            it.copy(name = "fred")   // <-- error here
        }
    }

}

But when I changed Bar to data class Bar everything compiles just fine.  What exactly is going on here?  Why does a plain class show up as Unit whereas a data class is correctly interpreted as type Bar?
And lastly, what should I do if I want the functionality of a full class and not a data class (ie inheritance)?

The reason for the mention of Unit in the error: Since a non-data class doesn’t have a copy() function, the compiler doesn’t know what the return type of this supposed copy() function should be, so it’s apparently using Unit as a default inferred return type. This cascades up to a secondary error about your update lambda returning the wrong type. Basically, one error triggers another error, leading to a confusing error message.
If you want Bar to be an open class instead of a data class you will have to manually create your own copy() function if you need one, but beware that the definition of what a copy is becomes ambiguous when there are subclasses. Probably the main reason it is forbidden to subclass a data class.
Note that it is fine for data classes to be subclasses of other types or interfaces. They just can’t have subclasses of their own.

The copy function is only available on data classes.
See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html.
Judging by how you've declared Bar, I'd say you should want that to be a data class. A data class should be something that holds data to be passed around your app that has no functionality, only data or state.
You can still achieve inheritance using sealed classes and have Bar as a data class.
